# how to draw a path of moving object in css animation without svg?

Tags: css, sass

I have a moving box (a div changed into a tiny box) on a html page. The box is moving in a curve path that I am describing in animation frames of css.

Now I have to draw a line following this box move, just to mimic a pencil move, so it looks like the line has been drawn by the moving box. As the box moves, a line should start appearing behind it, e.g. just like we draw a line by pen or pencil.

Not sure, if it is possible only in css but if you have any suggestion, please feel free to advice me. Thank you.

here is code
test.html

```
        <html>
         <head>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="box.css">
          </head>
          <body style="background-color: white;">      
             <div id="box">
               <div id="line"></div>
             </div>
         </body>
         <script src = "logo.js"></script>
       </html>
```

css file: box.css

```
body{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

#box {
  margin-top:300px;
  margin-left:30px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:30px;
  height:40px;
  background-color: red;
  animation:move-line;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes move-line {
  0%{
    transform:translateX(0px)translateY(0px) ;
  }
  50%{
    transform:translateX(280px)translateY(0px) ;
  }
  60%{
    transform:translateX(300px)translateY(-100px) ;
  }
  70%{
    transform:translateX(300px)translateY(100px) ;
  }
  80%{
    transform:translateX(320px)translateY(0px) ;
  }
  90%{
    transform:translateX(330)translateY(0px) ;
  }
  100%{
    transform:translateX(400px) ;
  }

}
```

javascript file: logo.js
currently it is empty but if you have a solution feel free to use it with javascript too however css is preferred.

Comment: Yes you can use just CSS. Draw the path in advance (using background linear-gradients on a container) then have a large pseudo after element on the box with a white background. As the box moves the lines will get revealed and the timing will be exact.

Comment: would be very helpful if you just a tiny bit of codepen?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet to demonstrate the idea.

An after pseudo element attached to the red box has a solid white background.

As the box moves, the pseudo element 'goes before it' revealing what is already underneath.

In this demo just the first part of the line has been drawn. You'll need to add the other lines with additional linear-gradients, 3 being at angles and positioned suitably and the last one horizontal again.

Alternatively you could put an image there instead of using linear gradients but I note your question says no SVG so I assume that maybe it isn't allowed a jpg either.

```html
<style>
  body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
  }
  
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0 calc(300px + 20px), black calc(300px + 20px) calc(301px + 20px), transparent calc(301px + 20px) 100%);
    background-size: 280px 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  
  #box {
    margin-left: 30px;
    top: 300px;
    left: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    animation: move-line;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  #box::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -300px;
    left: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  @keyframes move-line {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0px)translateY(0px);
    }
    50% {
      transform: translateX(280px)translateY(0px);
    }
    60% {
      transform: translateX(300px)translateY(-100px);
    }
    70% {
      transform: translateX(300px)translateY(100px);
    }
    80% {
      transform: translateX(320px)translateY(0px);
    }
    90% {
      transform: translateX(330)translateY(0px);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(400px);
    }
  }
</style>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="box.css">
</head>

<body style="background-color: white;">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="box">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="logo.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry could not understand what you are trying to do?I have solution for horizantal drawing and it works perfectly but things doesnt fit when it comes to angular drawing, as animation is pushing the draw line by few pixels.

Comment: Does the snippet when you run it make it look as though the box is 'drawing' the line? If you have the lines all there from the start, just covered up until the box moves, there is no possibility of the timing or positioning going wrong. Have you tried a linear gradient with a degree slope as part of the background?